# PowerShell ForEach removes leading zeros

Tags: powershell

I am kind of new with PowerShell and programming in general, so I hope you have some patience while reading this. Before I explain my problem, I feel like I have to first tell you some background information:

I have all my transactions saved in $Transactions. Each transaction has *Receiver*, *Date* and *Amount*.

I have grouped the yearly transactions into $TransactionsPerYear the following way:

```
$TransactionsPerYear = $Transactions | Group-Object { [int]($_.date -replace '.*\.') }
```

(Btw. Could someone explain the regex in the end for me, what each character does?)

Next thing I am doing is grouping yearly income and expenses into separate variables. After this I am trying to extract the months from each year and save them into $Months. The date is in the following format dd.MM.yyyy

**Question 1:**

Here's how I can get all the dates, but how do I extract just the months?

```
$TransactionsPerYear | Select -ExpandProperty Group | Select -ExpandProperty date | Select -Unique
```

**Question 2:**

Because I don't know how to extract the months, I've tried it the following way:

```
[String[]]$Months = "01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"
```

When I have each month in $Months I am trying to get monthly transactions and save them into new variables:

```
ForEach($Month in $Months){

New-Variable -Name "Transactions_$Month$Year" -Value ($Transactions | Where {$_.Date -like "*.$Month.$Year"} | Group-Object 'Receiver' | Select-Object Count, Name, @{L="Total";E={$_ | Select -ExpandProperty Group | Measure-Object Amount -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty Sum}} | Sort-Object {[double]$_.Total})

}
```

The problem that I am facing here is that ForEach removes the leading zero from each month, and when this happens, this part in ForEach doesn't match with anything, and the new variable is null:

```
Where {$_.Date -like "*.$Month.$Year"}
```

Let me know if you need more info. I'd be really thankful if anyone could help me.

The date looks like: 25.02.2016

Comment: can you share with us how the Date looks like? "dd.MM.yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy" and etc.

Comment: I have added it to the end of the post now.

Comment: i have tested your code and its working fine. do you have specified variable `$Year`?

Comment: Sometimes it works, and sometimes it removes the leading zero, that seems to be the problem. I don't know if it is a "feature" in PowerShell ISE or what is causing it, but anyways the current method is not reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your post, it looks like you've jumped further down the rabbithole than necessary.

Instead of trying to do string manipulation every time you need to interact with the `Date` property, simply turn it into a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) object!

```
$Transactions = $Transactions |Select-Object *,@{Name='DateParsed';Expression={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date, 'dd.MM.yyyy', $null)}}
```

The `DateTime.ParseExact()` method allows us to specify the format (eg. `dd.MM.yyyy`), and parse a string representation of a date.

Now you can group on year simply by:

```
$TransactionsPerYear = $Transactions |Group-Object { $_.DateParsed.Year }
```

---

To group by both Year and then Month, I'd create a nested hashtable, like so:

```
# Create a hashtable, containing one key per year
$MonthlyTransactions = @{}

foreach($Year in $Transactions |Group {$_.DateParsed.Year})
{
    # Create another hashtable, containing a key for each month in that year
    $MonthlyTransactions[$Year.Name] = @{}

    foreach($Month in $Year.Group |Group {$_.DateParsed.Month})
    {
        # Add the transactions to the Monthly hashtable
        $MonthlyTransactions[$Year.Name][$Month.Name] = $Month.Group
    }
}
```

Now you can calculate the transaction value for a specific month by doing:

```
$TotalValueMay2010 = ($MonthlyTransactions[2010][5] |Measure-Object Amount -Sum).Sum
```

---

> (Btw. Could someone explain the regex in the end for me, what each character does?)

Sure:

```
.   # match any character
 *  # zero of more times
\.  # match a literal . (dot)
```

Taking your own example input string `25.02.2016`, the first group (`.*`) will match on `25.02`, and `\.` will match on the `.` right after, so the only thing left is `2016`.

Comment: I am really trying figure out this. So the $MonthlyTransactions hash-table has keys like 2015, 2016 and values like 7, 11, 12. But this e.g. doesn't give me back anything $MonthlyTransactions[2015][7] even though it exists. Should it? It just says "Cannot index into a null array"

What I am trying to achieve is to get expenses, income, and total (income minus expenses) from each month. I am also trying to get all the transactions from each month, and group them by "receiver" and count how much money I've spent on each "receiver".

Comment: Okay, I think I got it, you should do it like this:
$MonthlyTransactions['2015']['7'] Thanks for your help Mathias!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
$dates = ([DateTime] "1/1/2016"),([DateTime] "1/2/2016"),
  ([DateTime] "2/1/2016"),([DateTime] "3/1/2016")
$uniqueMonths = $dates | ForEach-Object { $_.Month } | Sort-Object -Unique
# $uniqueMonths contains 1,2,3
```